# TomEE simple-mdb-with-descriptor does not work

Tags: java, message-driven-bean, apache-tomee

http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-mdb-with-descriptor/README.html

I tried this example as it is.. meaning,

1. copied all the code and created a jar file having META-INF/ejb-jar.xml in it.

   2. copied jar to my WAR project under project.war/lib/simple-mdb.jar

nothing happens in my TomEE .. not even "ChatBean" print statements on console

any one faced this similar issue?

Comment: Have you tried to run the ChatBeanTest ¿?.

Comment: no i did not... it was not readable for tomee so i started investing related thing with tomee... however i guess it is safe to assume that JUnit test would always work because it uses embedded ejb container to create bean  EJBContainer.createEJBContainer().getContext().bind("inject", this);